# hadoop2.2.0 append file occur AlreadyBeingCreatedException

Tags: java, hadoop, append

I have meet a problem about hadoop2.2.0 append operation. I append some bytes to a hdfs file by HDFS java API.First I will create the target file if the file doesn't exist before appending operation, the codes like:

```
String fileUri = "hdfs://hadoopmaster:9000/in/append_test.txt";
// create the hdfs file, if not exists
HdfsClient.createPathIfNotExist(fileUri);
// do 5 times append operation
for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    HdfsClient.appendTo(fileUri, ("append content"+i).getBytes("UTF-8"));
}
```

The `createPathIfNotExist` function:

```
Path p = null;
FileSystem fs = null;
try {
    fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
    p = new Path(uri);
    if (!fs.exists(p)) {
    if (uri.charAt(uri.length() - 1) == '/'){ //create a directory
        if(fs.mkdirs(p)){
               // create successfully
            }
        }else{ //create a file
        FSDataOutputStream fos = fs.create(p);
            fos.close();
        }
    } else{
        System.out.println(uri + "existing");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally{
    if (fs != null)
    try {
       fs.close();
       fs = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

The `appendTo` function:

```
ByteArrayInputStream in = null;
OutputStream out = null;
FileSystem fs = null;
try {
   in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
   fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
   out = fs.append(new Path(uri)); //get append outputstream
   IOUtils.copyBytes(in, out, bufferSize, false);
} catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
} finally{
   if (in != null) IOUtils.closeStream(in);
   if (out != null) IOUtils.closeStream(out);
   if (fs != null){
    try {
           fs.close();
           fs = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
}
```

The result is the append_test.txt is created, but the content only has:

```
append content0
```

And occur exception:

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.AlreadyBeingCreatedException): Failed to create file [/in/append_test.txt] for [DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1148656837_1] on client [192.168.141.1], because this file is already being created by [DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_2099912242_1] on [192.168.141.1]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2386)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFile(FSNamesystem.java:2347)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.append(NameNodeRpcServer.java:508)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.append(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:59572)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2048)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2042)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1347)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.append(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.append(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.append(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callAppend(DFSClient.java:1480)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.append(DFSClient.java:1520)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.append(DFSClient.java:1508)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$4.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:310)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$4.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:306)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.append(DistributedFileSystem.java:306)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.append(FileSystem.java:1160)
        at org.lh.blog.message.hadoop.HdfsClient$2.run(HdfsClient.java:130)
        at org.lh.blog.message.hadoop.HdfsClient$2.run(HdfsClient.java:1)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1471)
        at org.lh.blog.message.hadoop.HdfsClient.appendTo(HdfsClient.java:121)
        at org.lh.blog.message.hadoop.HdfsClient.appendTo(HdfsClient.java:110)
        at org.lh.blog.message.test.HdfsClientTests.testCreateFileBeforeAppend(HdfsClientTests.java:26)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

That says, it only did one time append operation after creating the nonexist file, other 4 append operations failed, occur above errors.
I have created the file before append, but it says `AlreadyBeingCreatedException`, I am some confused.

I also have some tries. I found the hdfs files created by java API, all can't do append operation. But the hdfs files created by hdfs command(etc, "hdfs dfs -put"), can do append operation.

Can you help me, give me some suggestions?

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: DId you found solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

To solve the issue,

1. Read the file contents and store it into a variable.
2. Add new content that you wish to append to this variable.
3. Re-create the file and write your contents back to it.

This process worked fine for me and solved the issue.

APPEND operation is expensive and if you're trying to attempt it in parallel, then this issue my arise. Hence re-create file and re-write the contents to it rather than appending.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by some bug in hadoop "append code". You can read more about that in this article:
[append content to a file in HDFS](http://hadoop4mapreduce.blogspot.com/2012/08/two-methods-to-append-content-to-file.html)

There is also provided solution for this issue. You can also call close() method on fs after create file, and get FileSystem again right before append operation. Works fine for me, but it's up to You.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the speculative action to false

```
job.setSpeculativeExecution(false);
```

or can create a file to some temporary location with the timestamp or any other variable things in path and merge the result to base path later