# A lot of AlreadyBeingCreatedException and LeaseExpiredException when writing parquet from spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, parquet

I have several parallel Spark jobs doing the same thing, they work on separate input/output dirs, at the end they write results to parquet from dataframe using one of the columns as a partitioner. Jobs with the biggest inputs often fail. Some of executors start to fail with below exceptions, then a stage fails and start recalculating a failed partition, if number of failed stages reaches 4(if it reaches, sometimes it doesn't and the whole job finishes successfully) the whole job is canceled.

Stages fails with these failure reasons(from spark UI):

1. org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException
2. Connection closed by
   peer

I tried to find clues on the Internet and it seems the reason maybe speculative execution, but I don't enable it in Spark, any other ideas what is the reason of that?

Spark job code:

```java
sqlContext
      .createDataFrame(finalRdd, structType)
      .write()
      .partitionBy(PARTITION_COLUMN_NAME)
      .parquet(tmpDir);
```

Exceptions in executors:

```java
16/09/14 11:04:06 ERROR datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer: Aborting task.
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.AlreadyBeingCreatedException): Failed to create file [/erm/data/core/internal/ekp/stg/tmp/Z_PLAN_OPER/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201609141104_0001_m_006023_0/partition=2/part-r-06023-482b0b4d-1174-4c76-b203-92b2b47c78cb.parquet] for [DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1489398656_198] for client [10.117.102.72], because this file is already being created by [DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-2049022202_200] on [10.117.102.15]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:3152)



org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException): No lease on /erm/data/core/internal/ekp/stg/tmp/Z_PLAN_OPER/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201609141105_0001_m_006489_0/partition=2/part-r-06489-482b0b4d-1174-4c76-b203-92b2b47c78cb.parquet (inode 318361396): File does not exist. Holder DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1428957718_196 does not have any open files.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkLease(FSNamesystem.java:3625)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.analyzeFileState(FSNamesystem.java:3428)   


Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.AlreadyBeingCreatedException): Failed to create file [/erm/data/core/internal/ekp/stg/tmp/Z_PLAN_OPER/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201609141105_0001_m_006310_0/partition=2/part-r-06310-482b0b4d-1174-4c76-b203-92b2b47c78cb.parquet] for [DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-419723425_199] for client [10.117.102.44], because this file is already being created by [DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_596138765_198] on [10.117.102.35]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:3152)


    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException): No lease on /erm/data/core/internal/ekp/stg/tmp/Z_PLAN_OPER/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201609141104_0001_m_005877_0/partition=2/part-r-05877-482b0b4d-1174-4c76-b203-92b2b47c78cb.parquet (inode 318359423): File does not exist. Holder DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_193375828_196 does not have any open files.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkLease(FSNamesystem.java:3625)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.analyzeFileState(FSNamesystem.java:3428)



    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.AlreadyBeingCreatedException): Failed to create file [/erm/data/core/internal/ekp/stg/tmp/Z_PLAN_OPER/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201609141104_0001_m_005621_0/partition=2/part-r-05621-482b0b4d-1174-4c76-b203-92b2b47c78cb.parquet] for [DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_498917218_197] for client [10.117.102.36], because this file is already being created by [DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-578682558_197] on [10.117.102.16]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:3152)


    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException): No lease on /erm/data/core/internal/ekp/stg/tmp/Z_PLAN_OPER/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201609141104_0001_m_006311_0/partition=2/part-r-06311-482b0b4d-1174-4c76-b203-92b2b47c78cb.parquet (inode 318359109): File does not exist. Holder DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-60951070_198 does not have any open files.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkLease(FSNamesystem.java:3625)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.analyzeFileState(FSNamesystem.java:3428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3284)


Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException): No lease on /erm/data/core/internal/ekp/stg/tmp/Z_PLAN_OPER/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201609141104_0001_m_006215_0/partition=2/part-r-06215-482b0b4d-1174-4c76-b203-92b2b47c78cb.parquet (inode 318359393): File does not exist. Holder DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-331523575_197 does not have any open files.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkLease(FSNamesystem.java:3625)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.analyzeFileState(FSNamesystem.java:3428)



Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.AlreadyBeingCreatedException): Failed to create file [/erm/data/core/internal/ekp/stg/tmp/Z_PLAN_OPER/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201609141104_0001_m_006311_0/partition=2/part-r-06311-482b0b4d-1174-4c76-b203-92b2b47c78cb.parquet] for [DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1869576560_198] for client [10.117.102.44], because this file is already being created by [DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-60951070_198] on [10.117.102.70]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:3152)
```

Spark UI:

[image]

We use Spark 1.6 (CDH 5.8)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655634/hadoop2-2-0-append-file-occur-alreadybeingcreatedexception

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @Ana Not really, it's been ages since, from what I can remember our cluster was sometimes unstable  and when that happened we got a lot of unusual error messages, this is just one type of them.

Comment: In my cluster, speculative execution is active, but still, this error is an indication to level up the cluster as you mentioned. These jobs used to run fine earlier, but as the number of jobs increased in cluster, such issues are increasing too on the same jobs that ran fine earlier.